# PDO Select Statement Echo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get this to echo out from the database and I know there is a problem but I don't know if it is not getting the information or if I am doing a wrong way getting it to echo it out I am new to using PDO.

```
<?php
include 'add/dbconnect.php';
function getfevent ($conn) {
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `event` WHERE `featured` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to echo?

Comment: @redelman431 I want it to echo the name from the database.Like on the 6th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested).

```
<?php
include 'add/dbconnect.php';
function getfevent ($conn) {
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `event` WHERE `featured` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$statement=$conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
while($row=$statement->fetch()) {
echo $row['name'];
}
}
getfevent ($conn);
?>
```

Comment: It is still not displaying anything

Comment: Try changing your SQL to just "SELECT `name` FROM `event`" to make sure there are rows being selected.

Comment: Also, are you sure that $conn has been declared as a PDO object? You are inside a function.

Comment: No I am not sure what would that look like and what would it be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20970/discussion-between-user1019588-and-maxgee)

Answer (score 3):

The call to `PDO::query` returns a `PDOStatement` object.  You do not just iterate over that object as you are trying to do.  You need to utilize the `fetch`, `fetchAll`, `fetchObject`, etc. methods on the `PDOStatement` object to access or iterate through the result set.

Comment: I am new to this kind of work so what would I need to change?

Comment: @maxgee check the documentation (http://www.php.net/pdo). It has usage and examples of all of the class methods mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get any error from PDO, try this:

```
INSERT INTO `event` (name, featured) VALUES ("name", 0)
```

Then see if your echo works :)

Comment: Wouldnt i want it to be select instead of inseret cause i dont want to replace anything just get something from the database.

Comment: The select stament works fine I made inside phpmyadmin and it got the results I wanted.